# Visual Studio 2015 temporary non response while compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I build a 10000-lines project with Visual Studio 2015 (c++), the program becomes 2-15 seconds non-responsive.

After a period of non-response, it can be used again (still compiling) for 2-4 second, then it goes non-response .... loop like this until finish.

```
while(compiling){
    Visual Studio unresponsive for 2-15 seconds. 
    Visual Studio responsive for 2-4 seconds.
}
```

This issue reduces productivity - I can't skim code while waiting.

This happens in both debug and release mode.

I doubt, if the reason is that I compiled it using multi-core flag, but I don't want to sacrifice that flag just to solve this issue.

Is it a common behavior?      Is it possible to fix?
I've searched but found only issue about permanent non-response (virtually crash).

Comment: ***Is it a common behavior?*** It happens to me but my projects are much larger than 10K lines. Not as noticeable on systems with SSDs.

Comment: Try to set `High` priority for Visual Studio process.

Comment: @Inline You mean task-manager?  Is it possible to set in the option/preference?

Comment: @javaLover Yes. I think there is no option for that, you can start executable with `/high` using batch file (`*.bat`) or file shortcut